# node soap not returning result but same input works in soap ui

Tags: web-services, soap, node-soap

I am unsure if this is a node-soap bug or if there is something i'm overlooking, but the input generated by the configuration options works fine in SoapUI. However, when I access the router link through Chrome passing the param_resoureid, it simply shows a blank screen.

```
ppmRouter.get("/get_time_sheet",(req,res,next) => {

    var resourceid = req.query.param_resourceid
    var soap = require('soap');
    var url = config.wsdlObjectPath + "TimePeriods"
    var sheader = { "Auth": {Username: config.xog_user, Password: config.password}}

    var args = { 
        ":NikuDataBus": {
            ":Header":{
                attributes: {
                    version: "6.0.11", 
                    action: "read", 
                    objectType: "timeperiod", 
                    externalSource: "NIKU"
                }
            },
            ":Query": {
                ":Filter": {
                    attributes: {
                    name: "resourceID",
                    criteria: "EQUALS"
                    },
                    $value: resourceid 
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var wsdlOptions = {
        overrideRootElement: {
          namespace: 'tns',
          xmlnsAttributes: []
        }
      };

    soap.createClient(url, wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {
        client.addSoapHeader(sheader,"","","");
        client.setEndpoint(config.xog_url)
        client.ReadTimeperiod(args,(error,result)=>{
            console.log(client.lastRequest)
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(result)
            res.send(result)
        })
    });
})
```

[Same Output from client.lastRequest works in SOAP UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erc6k.png)

Comment: Could you post also working sample definition in order to compare?

Comment: I just added an image to clarify.

Comment: Basically, the xml generated by the code is correct. However, for whatever reason, the client isn't retrieving the data, in order for me to forward the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work by using the args { _xml: `**code*`} option.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1TS Open Timesheet

ppmRouter.get("/get_time_sheet",(req,res,next) => {

    var resourceid = req.query.param_resourceid
    var soap = require('soap');
    var url = config.wsdlObjectPath + "TimePeriods"
    var sheader = { "tns:Auth": {"tns:Username": config.xog_user, "tns:Password": config.password}}

    var args = { 
        _xml: `
        <tns:ReadTimeperiod xmlns:tns="http://www.niku.com/xog/Object">
        <NikuDataBus>
        <Header version="6.0.11" action="read" objectType="timeperiod" externalSource="NIKU">
        </Header>
        <Query>
        <Filter name="resourceID" criteria="EQUALS">` + resourceid + `</Filter></Query>
        </NikuDataBus>
        </tns:ReadTimeperiod>`
    };

    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

        if (err) console.log(err)
        client.addSoapHeader(sheader,"","","");
        client.setEndpoint(config.xog_url)
        client.ReadTimeperiod(args,(error,result)=>{
            console.log(client.lastRequest)
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(result)
            res.send(result)
        })
    });
})
```